# Не получается распарсить json ответ

Tags: javascript, json

Из `ajax` запроса в скрипт приходит примерно такой ответ:

```
{"results":
{"ser19":{"io_ver":1.01,"ch_ver":"1.99","need_update":true},
"ser20":{"io_ver":1.01,"ch_ver":"1.53","need_update":true}
}}
```

В скрипте пытаюсь распарсить его и вывести на страницу (в переменной `dt` как раз `json` приведенный выше):

```
                    alert("y: " + dt);
                    var data_arr = JSON.parse(dt);
                    var x;
                    alert("x: " + data_arr.ser19.ch_ver);
                    for(x in data_arr){
                        $("#upd_res").append(data_arr[x].ch_ver);
                    }
```

И проблема в том, что первый `alert` выводит:

```
y: [object Object]
```

А весь остальной код не срабатывает, т.е. все что после:

```
var data_arr = JSON.parse(dt);
```

не выводится, в т.ч. и второй `alert`

```
alert("x: " + data_arr.ser19.ch_ver);
```

Подскажите как распарсить такой `JSON`  в `JavaScript` и вывести его в виде текста:

```
ser19 - ch_ver 1.99
ser20 - ch_ver 1.53
```

Comment: `alert("x: " + data_arr.results.ser19.ch_ver);`

Comment: не работает, даже алерт не выводит! И ошибок никаких, смотрю в firebug в firefox

Comment: скорее всего json уже преобразован в объект ajax методом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var dt = '{"results":\
{"ser19":{"io_ver":1.01,"ch_ver":"1.99","need_update":true},\
"ser20":{"io_ver":1.01,"ch_ver":"1.53","need_update":true}\
}}';

var data_arr = JSON.parse(dt).results;
console.log("x: " + data_arr.ser19.ch_ver);
var x;
for (x in data_arr) {
  console.log(data_arr[x].ch_ver);
}
```

Если `dt` это уже объект, то

```js
var dt = {"results":
{"ser19":{"io_ver":1.01,"ch_ver":"1.99","need_update":true},
"ser20":{"io_ver":1.01,"ch_ver":"1.53","need_update":true}
}};

var data_arr = dt.results;
console.log("x: " + data_arr.ser19.ch_ver);
var x;
for (x in data_arr) {
  console.log(data_arr[x].ch_ver);
}
```